# Issue with Tomcat 8.0.26 and any java version after jdk1.8.0_11

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a test tomcat server that our developers use to test their apps.  We have about 44 small apps (40-80MB).  If I run tomcat 8.0.26 with jdk1.8.0_05 or jdk1.8.0_11 all the apps load find and are available to users.

If I use jdk 1.8.0_20 or later versions the server crashes with memory errors after loading about 15 apps.

The server is a SuSE Linux Enterprise 11 SP3.  8 GB RAM , 2 VCPU's

I'm using the same JAVA_OPTS for each test.

JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m"

Just wondering what changes were made after jdk1.8.0_11 that could cause these issues?

```
%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
    at peigov.toolkit.dao.base.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.<clinit>(HibernateSessionFactory.java:38)
    at peigov.toolkit.dao.base.hibernate.GenericHibernateDAO.getSession(GenericHibernateDAO.java:78)
    at peigov.toolkit.dao.base.hibernate.GenericHibernateDAO.findByPropertiesOrderBy(GenericHibernateDAO.java:258)
    at peigov.toolkit.service.GenericManager.findByPropertiesOrderBy(GenericManager.java:97)
    at peigov.toolkit.service.impl.StrutsPermissionManager.getPersistedActions(StrutsPermissionManager.java:83)
    at peigov.toolkit.service.impl.StrutsPermissionManager.rebuildActionsFromConfig(StrutsPermissionManager.java:61)
    at peigov.toolkit.auth.permissions.StrutsPermissionsPlugin.init(StrutsPermissionsPlugin.java:18)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:871)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:359)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:259)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource$JarInputStreamWrapper.read(AbstractArchiveResource.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource.getContent(AbstractArchiveResource.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2611)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2428)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:85)
    ... 43 more
01-Sep-2015 09:29:08.373 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1499)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:259)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource$JarInputStreamWrapper.read(AbstractArchiveResource.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource.getContent(AbstractArchiveResource.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2611)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2428)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.error(Log4JLogger.java:257)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:398)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    ... 4 more

mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file
01-Sep-2015 09:29:08.375 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1499)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    ... 4 more

mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file
01-Sep-2015 09:29:08.375 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1499)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    ... 4 more

mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file
01-Sep-2015 09:29:08.376 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1499)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to the SO. Could you please provide an error message itself ? I believe no one will not help you about debugging of that issue.

Comment: Would be easier to help if you show the error you getting.

Comment: I've added a clipping from the catalina.out file where the out of memory errors start.